# Web Server in IIS stops time after time

Tags: web-services, iis-6

I have developed a web service in c# (ASP.NET), and published it in IIS 6.1 (Windows Server 2008). Web application takes data from this web service, but time after time it does not return anything. After I restart web service it works again normally. I don't understand why web service stops returning result time after time. What can cause this? Any help please?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without knowing any details. But an approach would be checking the event logs.

Comment: I could see in event viewer just information about that web service:"A worker process with process id of '14328' serving application pool 'Name of WebService' was shutdown due to inactivity.  Application Pool timeout configuration was set to 20 minutes.  A new worker process will be started when needed."        No error i can see.

Answer (score 0):

Set the Idle timeOut for an Application Pool to 0 instead of default value of 20 minutes for having no timeout when your service is idle.

**using inetmgr**

- Open IIS Manager. For information about opening IIS Manager, see Open
  IIS Manager (IIS 7).
- In the **Connections** pane, expand the server node and click **Application
  Pools.**
- On the **Application Pools** page, select the application pool for
  which you want to specify idle time-out settings, and then click
  **Advanced Settings** in the **Actions** pane.
- In the **Idle Time-out (minutes)** box, type a number of minutes, and then click **OK**.

**uisng cmd**

> appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name=' string
>   '].processModel.idleTimeout: timeSpan

```
 appcmd set config /section:applicationPools /[name=' Marketing '].processModel.idleTimeout:0.00:30:00
```